# How would I redirect an error from a failed if condition

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stderr

I am trying to better understand STDERR and when/where to place 2> within the initial testing phase of a loop.

**My script is as follows...**

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=/tmp/file1
file2=/tmp/file2

if [ -e $file1 -o -e $file2 ]; then
  if ls $file1 2>> err.log ; then
     echo "file1 exists" | tee -a job.log
  fi

  if ls $file2 2>> err.log ; then
    echo "file2 exists" | tee -a job.log
  fi
else
 echo "neither $file1 or $file2 exists"
fi
```

However, when file1 or file2 does NOT exist, I would expect the following to be appended to err.log

**ls: cannot access /tmp/file1: No such file or directory**

But nothing gets written to err.log whatsoever...not sure what I am missing, but I thought the logic was straightforward.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me...
`$ touch /tmp/file1
$ ./foo 
/tmp/file1
file1 exists
$ cat err.log 
ls: cannot access /tmp/file2: No such file or directory
`

Comment: why are you even using `ls` in a test?  why not just `[ ! -e "$file1" ] && echo "$file1 does not exist" >>err.log`?    BTW, the general answer to "when do I redirect stderr?" is "whenever you want to save stderr to a file or pipe it into another process"

Comment: General code comment - always make sure your `"$variables"` are inside double quotes when you use them. `echo "This is a $variable"` is good. As is `[ -e "$file" ]`.

Comment: @roaima ...thank you, great advice kind sir

Answer (score 4):

As cas points out, you are unnecessarily using `ls`.  Your script could be written as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1='/tmp/file1'
file2='/tmp/file2'

if [[ -e "$file1" ]]; then
    echo "file1 exists" | tee -a job.log
else
    echo 'ls: cannot access /tmp/file1: No such file or directory' >>err.log
fi
if [[ -e "$file2" ]]; then
    echo "file2 exists" | tee -a job.log
else
    echo 'ls: cannot access /tmp/file2: No such file or directory' >>err.log
fi
[[ ! -e "$file1" && ! -e "$file2" ]] && echo "neither $file1 or $file2 exists"
```

The ls errors should probably be changed but it is what you wanted to see in your error file so I left them :)

Comment: His goal is to learn about STDERR, and why his redirection didn't seem to be working.

Comment: @user1404316; yes but his redirection wasn't working the way he wanted because of flaws in his code that IanC pointed out...however since he posted his code I have improved it rather than pointing him to the countless other questions on here about how to redirect `stderr`.  (His stderr redirect was fine, it's the conditional statements that were a problem).

Comment: It was my understanding that 2>> err.log  sends error output to the file.... in my code i have absolutely NO idea why its not sending the "ls" error to where i'm directing it (err.log), given the fact the file does not exist.  i thought i followed the logic.  But in any case, i thank Cas, Ian and Jesse_b logic....

Comment: @Leonard you are absolutely right about redirecting stderr.  Yours wasn't working because as IanC points out you were never hitting the lines with `ls` in them if both files don't exist.

Comment: @Jesse_b ...now that i look at it, you're totally right, i totally missed that....because in my first IF, i was saying "-e" (if exist, then)....i can see how that code wasn't even being read.

Comment: @Leonard: Please upvote and mark IanC's answer.  He found that flaw.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be written to the file if at least one of the files exists. If both don't exist the `if` statement will jump straight to the `else` clause which doesn't run `ls` at all.

If you want to append the error message if **both** files don't exist you can do it manually in the `else` clause like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=/tmp/file1
file2=/tmp/file2

if [ -e $file1 -o -e $file2 ]; then
  if ls $file1 2>> err.log ; then
     echo "file1 exists" | tee -a job.log
  fi

  if ls $file2 2>> err.log ; then
    echo "file2 exists" | tee -a job.log
  fi
else
 echo "neither $file1 or $file2 exists"
 ls $file1 2>> err.log
 ls $file2 2>> err.log
fi
```

That will run the `ls` command even when you know the files don't exist, so you have the command error logged in your file.

Note that the code doesn't make much sense in a practical point of view, but if it's written for the sole purpose of learning then that shouldn't matter..

Comment: ...thanks guys...this clears things up a LOT for me...i am going to revisit my file exists script and play with my logic some more.